# Have some elements of a qml / qtquick2 column in a separate file

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a situation like this:

```
Column{
 Item{id:item1}
 Item{id:item2}
 Item{id:item3}
 Item{id:item4}
 Item{id:itemA}
}

Column{
 Item{id:item1}
 Item{id:item2}
 Item{id:item3}
 Item{id:item4}
 Item{id:itemB}
}
```

Can i achieve the following with a custom qml element?

```
Column{
 ItemsOneToFour{}
 Item{id:itemA}
}

Column{
 ItemsOneToFour{}
 Item{id:itemB}
}
```

As I understand qml, custom elements (or qml elements in general) need to have only one single root, but it would be really helpful in case of columns, rows and grids (or positioners in general) to be able to reuse some parts for e.g. other columns, so I hope that Im just lacking some knowledge on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, but you can have:

```
Column{ // ItemsOneToFour
 Item{id:item1}
 Item{id:item2}
 Item{id:item3}
 Item{id:item4}
}

ItemsOneToFour{
 Item{id:itemA}
}

ItemsOneToFour{
 Item{id:itemB}
}
```

That's how it actually works.

On a side note, it would have been nice if QML supported interfaces, but it doesn't. So aggregation is the way to go.